# requireNativeComponent: "RCTNodeCamera" was not found in the UIManager. Regards

Tags: react-native, expo

please help me with this error in expo 41. I am creating a live stream app using react-native-nodemediaclient lib and mux in a expo managed workflow.
Error: is
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTNodeCamera" was not found in the UIManager.
Regards.

Comment: Have you been able to find the solution?

Comment: Has the solution been found?

Answer (score 0):

You should clean your build and build again.

`expo r -c`